# End USA Citizenship inside USA During War

Tags: usa, citizenship

Nationality Act includes a section and bunch of clauses on how citizenship can be lost. From [here.](http://travel.state.gov/content/travel/english/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/renunciation-of-citizenship-right-of-residence.html)

> (6) making in the United States a formal written renunciation of nationality in such form as may be prescribed by, and before such officer as may be designated by, the Attorney General, whenever the United States shall be in a state of war and the Attorney General shall approve such renunciation as not contrary to the interests of national defense;

Is this clause in effect? Who are the officers? Would the person doing this be deported?

Edit; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renunciation_Act_of_1944) I don't know how I missed this page. Is all of the information true? My last question is still not answered.

Comment: How is it a question about expats?

Comment: Is there a better place to post this question? Do you really want to splint all of these nationality and citizenship questions across 2 sites?

Comment: @ran8: There being a better place to ask the question is not a prerequisite for it being off-topic here.  I know of no appropriate SE site to ask this question.

Comment: This question is about expats because I would become one. Topics regarding gaining citizenship and just becoming an expat qualify even if poster is not an expat yet. All examples to right in related section. Topmost one questions a clause one clause away from mine and qualifies under the exact same 'loosing citizenship' reasoning.

Comment: The site is in its very early format so now is the time to decide what's on and off topic. There are other citizenship questions and its pretty close to immigration which has plenty of questions. If it were up to me I would seriously think about naming the site "Expatriates and Immigration" or deciding Immigration is separate and needs to start its own proposal. Anyway you need to discuss it!

Comment: @ran8: If you're still in the US, you're not becoming an expat. You're just forfeiting your citizenship. To be an expat, you must change location, too.

Comment: I think it's clear this question is *not* about expatriation. However, it might still be reasonable to expand the scope of this site to include such questions. I suggest opening a meta question to discuss it.

Comment: [works from usa, not expat might loose citizenship](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/146/can-i-lose-my-us-citizenship-for-accepting-employment-with-a-foreign-government?rq=1) But good point on the still in USA. Editing article.